# Capybara does not wait for factory_girl to finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Given the following simple spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Feeds', %q{
  In order see the latest content of Buurtlink
  As a user
  I should be able to view a neighborhood or postal_code
} do

  background do
    @neighborhood = FactoryGirl.create(:neighborhood_with_posts)
  end

  scenario 'Visitor views a neighborhood' do
    visit neighborhood_path(@neighborhood)

    find('#header_title').should have_content 'Diemen-Zuid'

    10.times do |index|
      expect(page).to have_text "Title of new post #{index}"
    end
  end

end
```

This test randomly fails. No JS is used on the page, but Capybara seems to visit the neighborhood_path before FactoryGirl is done creating all necessary posts. When looking at the page using save_and_open_page I can see that sometimes not all posts have been created yet.

Simply adding sleep 1 above visit neighborhood_path fixes the problem, but that's not a solution.

I'm using RSpec, Capybara, Spork and DatabaseCleaner. I also monkey-patched ActiveRecord so that it uses a shared connection.

Comment: Interesting, I never met that before. Could you show the factory code as well as failing messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in the ApplicationController:

```
def load_posts_after_current_time
  session[:load_posts_after] = DateTime.now unless params[:page].present?
end
```

Therefore, errors occurred when fetching newly created records. So added created_at 1.hour.ago to the post factory.

```
  factory :post do
    user { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    created_at 1.hour.ago

    factory :neighborhood_post do
      association :postable, factory: :_neighborhood_post
    end
  end
```

It works!

Comment: mmm, why `Simply adding sleep 1 above visit neighborhood_path fixes the problem, but that's not a solution.` ?

Comment: Probably because there's a scope on fetching all posts saying where('created_at < ?', session[:load_posts_after])

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your background block:

```
let!(:neighborhood){FactoryGirl.create(:neighborhood_with_posts)}
```

and you can do

```
 visit neighborhood_path(neighborhood)
```

Comment: background is simply syntactic sugar for before. Using before does not change anything.

Comment: I have edited the answer for another solution. See if that works.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a sneaky session variable messing things up. See my answer.